# Upperbound for Norm of Lagged Autocovariance Matrix

Tags: time-series, probability, mathematical-statistics, expected-value, covariance-matrix

Suppose $X_t$ is a vector valued time series in $\mathbb{R}^d$. Assume for the moment that $X_t$ is stationary with $EX_t=0$, $E\|X_t\|^2<\infty$, and let

$$
C_h = E[X_0 X_h^\top]
$$
denote the autocovariance matrix at lag $h$. What I wish to show is that

$$
\|C_h\|_2 \le \|C_0\|_2,
$$
or find a counterexample to this statement. Here $\|\cdot\|_2$ is the Hilbert-Schmidt Norm:
$$\|A\|_2^2 = \sum_{i,j=1}^d a_{i,j}^2. $$

So far all I can show is the weaker statement that
$$
\|C_h\|_2 \le trace(C_0).
$$

To see this, we have by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality for expectation and stationarity that
$$
\|C_h\|_2^2 = \sum_{i,j=1}^d (E[X_{0,i}X_{h,j}])^2 \le  \sum_{i,j=1}^d E[X_{0,i}^2]E[X_{h,j}^2] = \sum_{i,j=1}^d E[X_{0,i}^2]E[X_{0,j}^2] =[trace(C_0)]^2.
$$
Part of me believes that this bound must be sharp (i.e. there is a counter example), but I really have no idea! Any help/advice is much appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason you're choosing to bound the HS norm of the lagged autocovariance matrix? In view of Cauchy-Schwarz inequality (applied to the HS inner product), it's more natural to estimate trace of $C_h$.

Comment: Hi Michael! Basically I wanted to come up with a simple summary statistic like the auto correlation function for multivariate time series. Given my inequality, a natural candidate is $\|C_h\|/trace(C_0)$, although $\|C_h\|/\|C_0\|$ seems more reasonable. However, I cannot show that the latter is between 0 and 1. Clearly the former is. I assumed there might be a counter example for the latter, but I cannot come up with that either (i.e. an example where $\|C_h\|/\|C_0\|>1$, obviously the dimension here would have to exceed 1). I'm just looking for a proof or counter example.

Comment: "...$\|C_h\|/\|C_0\|$ seems more reasonable" is my question. Why insist on taking the HS norm of $C_h$, when it's more natural to take $trace (C_h)$ from the HS perspective? Then you immediately get a quantity between 0 and 1 by Cauchy-Schwaz.

Comment: That is a fair point! Although the question remains as to if $\|C_h\|/\|C_0\|$ is bounded or not. Does $trace(C_h)=0$ imply $C_h=0$ in this case, since $C_h$ is not necessarily positive definite? That may be another drawback of the trace here.